Places in Taipei related with Edward Yang's films
I plan to visit Taipei, Taiwan this fall, and as a big fan of the film director Edward Yang（楊德昌）, I want to consult about where I can find some scenes appearing in his films like ‘Yi Yi’ （《一一》）or ‘A Confucian Confusion’（《獨立時代》）.
I heard that the wedding ceremony in the film ‘Yi Yi’ was set in the Grand Hotel (圓山大飯店）, but I guess it has been frequently refurbished over the past decades, so it may not be that reminiscent. Anyway, any suggestions would be very welcome！

In case you had not seen this: https://taiwan-scene.com/2021/04/08/on-location-the-big-screen-guide-to-exploring-the-city/

@MastaBaba Great help! Thanks a lot.

You might get better answers on Movies.SE as they actually have a [flim-location] tag.

@PeterM Thanks, I would try it.
